# Auto populate a field from another list based on the filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

I have a scenario in which a ListA has two dropdown fields(dropdown1 & dropdown2) with look ups and a multiline field for description. Dropdown1 is a lookup for a listB called countries. Dropdown2 is a lookup to a field in listC called regions with a cascading effect i.e if a user selects "CountryA" dropdown1, dropdown2 is automatically filtered with the regions of the countryA . ListC has more fields like country, region, description etc.

My question how can I autopopulate the description field from ListC based on the dropdown1 & dropdown2 selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To auto-populate a field based on two drop-down fields, I suggest you using InfoPath and set the description default value as below:

Add a data filter which make ListC data connection relevant fields equal to the current drop-down fields value.

[image]