# Cascading drop down fields

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a SharePoint list which includes multiple drop down columns. What I need to do is when I select a item from the first drop down column (which is a look up column) the second drop down column should show options only related to the value in the first column. I am using SharePoint 2013 online version. Is there a possible way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPServices Cascaded Dropdowns, thanks to Mark.

[SharePoint 2013: Cascade Dropdown List using SPServices](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37676.sharepoint-2013-cascade-dropdown-list-using-spservices-spservices-spcascadedropdowns.aspx)

[SPCascadeDropdowns](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/wiki/SPCascadeDropdowns)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for response. I tried both links and did the examples the exact way. But still it does not work as in the filters do not work. I tried using online libraries for jquery and SP services too. Anyways Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, Quick question. How can I know that the embedded script is linked to the code? As in how does the filtration trigger according to the above mentioned examples?

Comment: You can debug it using Chrome Developer Tools (F12), you can put alerts in the JS code to check if the code is actually been called etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to use InfoPath to customize the form.

You can follow the similar post below:

[Auto populate a field from another list based on the filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233223/auto-populate-a-field-from-another-list-based-on-the-filter)

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. I'm unable to use Infopath because I think it is not compatible with the version I use. I get an error message when I try to use InfoPath. Any other solution I could use? Thanks again :)

Comment: We can also use PowerApps in SharePoint Online to create cascading drop down list. check the blog: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Community-Blog/SharePoint-Cascading-Dropdowns-in-4-Easy-Steps/ba-p/16248

Comment: Hi! Many thanks to this solution. It worked just fine. But when I enter data through powerapps and save, the data I entered is not saved in the list. this happens with the  datafields I modified using powerapps. Any idea why?